# Yii2 migration on Microsoft SQL Server issue with identity column

Tags: sql-server, yii2, migration

I'm having an issue when using Yii2 migration with MS SQL Server. The migration scripts were working fine with MySQL database. However when I ran the migration on MS SQL Server the following error were shown:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'my_table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I've included the following code before running the batch insert statement in order to turn the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on:

`if ($this->db->driverName === 'sqlsrv' || $this->db->driverName === 'dblib' || $this->db->driverName === 'mssql') {
    $this->execute('SET IDENTITY_INSERT {{%my_table}} ON');
}`

However, the error still persist and I'm unable to complete the migration.

Answer (score 0):

be sure the command for set to ON  is executed  .. and that the executed  code is eaxactly what you need ..  for  this you can try the execution form a sql console  ..  instead  of the execution inside the migration ..

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT my_table ON;
```

be sure that you don't insert an explict value for the column you set as indentity ..

try using  an insert without  indentity column name and related  value

eg: Instead of this

```
INSERT my_table (my_identity_column, col2, col3, ...)
VALUES (my_identity_value, col2value, col3value, ...)
```

try

```
INSERT my_table ( col2, col3, ...)
VALUES ( col2value, col3value, ...)
```